# DB2 database is not returning query even though JDBC connection is successful, returns error

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, db2, websphere, db2-zos

I am trying to connect to a DB2 database using JDBC. The JDBC connection is successful, but the moment query is executed, it returns exception. On further analysis, following error is returned:

> Error code - -30025 Localized Error message -> ;DSN12015:*:V12R1M502;0600;0002

Checking the error code on IBM docs, it said something about setting APPL COMPAT LEVEL to BIND/REBIND etc which made no sense to me as I am new to SQL like DB2.

I am trying to operate the above on my personal laptop with Windows 10.

Anybody who can guide me around this would be a great help !

Same error (404) is returned when the same is run Eclipse in server using Tomcat.

Comment: Talk with experts for Db2-for-Z/OS at your site. They will know the plan for phasing in new functions in  the target subsystem. They may also advise you on client side changes that may help. __this is configuration__ .  You can also set a special register (at your client) for application compatibility (value V12R1M500 or lower) using one of the methods described here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjv00019.html

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [IBM Knowledge Center for DB2 error code -30025](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n30025.html) for more information.  Looking over the [help text](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n30025.html#n30025__dbresponse) in the `Database administrator response` section (since your identifier is in the format `product-identifier:*:package-applcompat-value` and it looks like you are dealing with a reason code 600), it gives you two options:

1. Upgrade the client or driver. Refer to [V12R1Mnnn application compatibility levels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_applcompatclients.html?view=kc).
2. If it is not yet possible to upgrade the client or driver, bind or rebind the client or driver packages with the APPLCOMPAT value set to V12R1M500 or lower.

Note:  This is just a basic summary, please review the entire section on [the help text page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n30025.html#n30025__dbresponse) for additional information.

Comment: Sir, I read your blogs too...I already read the help that as mentioned in my question. What i want to know is how to proceed about it from my computer to set APPLCOMPAT value. i tried executing queries and applying the same, but did not work...please guide me as a student, who has no clue

Comment: Did you try talking to the zOS DB2 admins like mao suggested?